# Models Associations Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want to know your opinion before start coding something.

Now I have the following models

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, :dependent => :destroy 
    devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :diseases, :dependent => :destroy #if you delete a person you also delete all diseases related
    has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy

    validates_presence_of :name, :email
    validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "name is too long"}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: "is invalid" }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :diseases, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }

end
```

It has to work like this:

One user could have n dependent persons (children, handicapped persons...) but at the same time that person should be able to have his own user and dependent people.

¿Any suggestion? ¿Should I use a has_many_and_belongs_to though some other model between user and person?

Thanks!

---

Please consider User as Supporter and Person as Dependant
This is what I was thinking about, something like this:

```
class Relationship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :person
end

class User
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :people, through: :relationships
end

class Person
  has_many :relationships
  has_many_and_belong_to :users, through: :relationships
end
```

Comment: The `has_and_belongs_to_many` association type in Rails doesn't accept the `through` option. Instead you probably want to write `has_many :users, through: :relationships`.

Comment: Yes, right. I made it following your nice explanation yesterdary. I think I've got it working, now Im testing. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `has_many :through` association should work in this situation.

I'm not 100% clear on the differences between `User` and `Person` so I'm going to take a little bit of licence and deal with the `Person` model for the moment but you could easily take this idea and apply it to the `User` instead.

The join model could be something like,

```
class Relationship
  belongs_to :dependant, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :supporter, class_name: 'Person'
end

class User
  ...
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :dependants, through: :relationships
  has_many :supporters, through: :relationships
end
```

Comment: Thanks Felix! I posted what I was thinking about, does it look correct in your opinion?